# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped) how to free() properly

Tags: c, pointers

I have searched the problem I am facing but couldn't solve it from the given answers to others. So I am here.

here is the code:

```
    char *readFile(char *filename) {
        FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rt");
        assert(f);
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        long length = ftell(f);
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        char *buffer = (char *) malloc(length + 1);
        buffer[length] = '\0';
        fread(buffer, 1, length, f);
        fclose(f);
        
        return buffer;
    }
   int main(){
char *content = readFile("filename");
free() // what to do here?
}
```

here is the error:

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I apologize if I am asking too simple questions. I am pretty new.

Comment: `free(&length + 1);` not sure what you are trying to do there. Can you please explain? `length` was not dynamically allocated so should not be freed. And no idea what the `+1` is for.

Comment: `free(&length + 1)`??? `length` is a `long` (so `4`-bytes on x86 or `8`-bytes on x86_64). So freeing the address of `length + 1` attempts to free an address located somewhere on your function stack (or in the odd case 1-byte after) -- which will cause all kinds of *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: @kaylum I am using the malloc() function for the first time and as I read, after using malloc() we should free() it to prevent memory leak and the freeing process should be the opposite of the malloc(). That's why I am using free() but I don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Isn't it at the heap?

Comment: You can't free in the function if you `return buffer;` -- otherwise you will have freed what you allocated and be returning a pointer than now points to an address that you can no longer validly access. If you want to return the allocated `buffer` (which is 100% okay), then just don't `free()` anything in the function and the caller will be responsible for calling `free()` when it is done with the information.

Comment: The argument to `free()` has to be a pointer that was returned by `malloc()`. `&length + 1` was not returned from `malloc()`.

Comment: The `malloc` and `free` rule is simple - whatever `malloc` returns is the exact pointer that needs to be passed to `free`. But `free` should only be called when the allocated memory is no longer needed. In your case the pointer to be eventually freed is `buffer`. But since you are returning the pointer to the caller you must not free it. In this case it is the caller's responsibility to call `free` once the buffer is no longer needed.

Comment: No, when you try to `free (&length + 1)` you are trying to free the address of `length` which  is a variable with *Automatic Storage Duration* that resides on the function stack. But the block of allocated memory whose address you assign to `buffer` will be allocated on the heap (but note, stack and heap are just conventions for separate memory areas -- the standard does not mention either)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am not capable to call free() in the caller function either. How would I do that?

Comment: Let's say in the calling function you do something line `char *contents = readFile(filename); if (contents) printf ("%s\n", contents);` after you have used `contents` however you like, you can `free(contents);` The key is this. `malloc` (`calloc`, and `realloc`) return the beginning address to an allocated block of memory. You can assign the address, return it, do anything you like with it -- so long as you preserve a pointer to it. That pointer is what you use to call `free()` regardless of the name of the pointer. It is the address held by the pointer that is important.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin everything's fine and clear now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yay! Good luck with your coding!